# GWT - stylish list box

Tags: gwt

Since I do not find select-boxes to be appealing, I wonder if something like the dropdown-box Google is using on its signup-page (for birthdate and gender) is available for GWT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a couple, but they all suck in my opinion (or at least their default styles are horrible) or haven't been maintained for a while.

- [ComboBox from SmartGWT](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#styled_combobox_category)
- [ComboBox from Ext GWT](http://www.sencha.com/examples/pages/forms/combos.html)
- http://code.google.com/p/gwt-structs/wiki/HtmlEnabledDropDown
- http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-incubator/wiki/DropDownListBox

Maybe others. But I would just write my own. The first 2 are not too bad I suppose, but you have to use SmartGWT or ExtGWT.